# What is the simplest way to integrate PayPal & Firebase?

Tags: paypal, firebase, firebase-security

I'd like to create this simple model:

1. user registers and Firebase stores email & password
2. user pays with PayPal to access protected content
3. Firebase gets notified by PayPal the user has paid & logs this
4. paying user logs in with his credentials & Firebase authorizes access to the protected content; non-paying users are denied access

What is the bare minimum amount of functionality needed to leverage Firebase's backend and make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your exact requirements (ie, are 5 or 15 minute delays acceptable) but you can get started super quickly using Zapier

https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/paypal/

You would setup the zap using your secret firebase and paypal keys, setting the zap to update a property on the user's profile (be sure to use Firebase security rules to limit write access to that property) which says they have paid.

Comment: 15 minute delays for a user who has just paid would be unacceptable. Since there is only a single message between Firebase and PayPal, isn't there a simple way to make the link directly?

Comment: @user1891836 The [PayPal service on Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/paypal/) lists all those triggers as "instant" meaning, no wait time. If you want faster than that, well, you're on your own :)

Comment: @user1891836 - "simple" when it comes to coding depends on your skill level. If you're fluent in NodeJS then yeah it's simple to write the code. My suggestion takes the programming out of it and leverages a solid platform for connecting services together. Now, I mentioned a 5 or 15 minute delay based upon my own research of integrating Firebase and Stripe via Zapier but it looks like Kato is right - Paypal is listed as Instant so I'd recommend you read up on it.

Comment: if Zapier can update Firebase instantly, that would be the simplest way. Mike, by "simple" I meant avoiding unnecessary coding as much as possible as I am certainly not a JS ninja. Finally, if the zap works as expected, how should I go about authorization with Firebase?

Comment: @user1891836 - when you walk through the Zap wizard, it will ask you for a Firebase secret token which you can get from accessing the 'Secrets' tab of your Firebase dashboard. This will give Zapier privileged access to your firebase forge. Use Firebase security rules to block end users from updating the data that you only want Zapier to update.

Comment: @user1891836 - I think I misinterpreted your last question. You could authorize users with Firebase using the Firebase Simple Login api. Is the content you're trying to authorize stored within Firebase? If not, it's going to be more challenging - you'll need to setup some code that executes on the server to serve the content and verify an authenticated user.

Comment: I'm looking to serve static content only (HTML & CSS), which I need to somehow protect from unauthorized access. I'll be registering and logging users using Firebase's API, and I only need PayPal to update a user's record once to verify he is paying. Do I need a server-side script to prevent the content from being served and how would that look like with Firebase?

Comment: Well - Firebase security is meant to protect data stored in Firebase. If you're just trying to protect static content, then you may want to consider other options such as a Wordpress site with an e-Commerce plugin. Otherwise you're going to need to write some server side code (.NET, Java, NodeJS, Ruby, whatever) that can validate the authentication cookie from Firebase Simple Login.. but that's all needless complexity for your use case.